# While loop in foreach loop not looping correctly

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make a *very* basic php ORM as for a school project. I have got almost everything working, but I'm trying to map results to an array. Here's a snippet of code to hopefully assist my explanation.

```
$results = array();

foreach($this->columns as $column){

    $current = array();

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($this->results)){
        $current[] = $row[$column];
        print_r($current);
        echo '<br><br>';
    }

    $results[$column] = $current;

}

print_r($results);

return mysql_fetch_array($this->results);
```

This works, but the while loop only works on the first column. `The print_r($results);` shows the following:

```
Array ( [testID] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 ) [testName] => Array ( ) [testData] => Array ( ) )
```

Can anybody shed some light?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can't see the need for going through the columns manually, the `MYSQL_ASSOC` flag on `mysql_fetch_array` will give you an array with only the column names as indices anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you already fetched every row, and the internal pointer is at the end.
The next while, mysql_fetch_array() will immediately return false.
You can reset the pointer to the first row:

```
mysql_data_seek($this->results, 0);
```

Put this just before

```
while($row = mysql_...
```

Comment: Thanks heaps! fixed it completely! Just one question: is there an equivalent when looping through a nested array?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can use the -> operator in a variable name.  As you trying to get the key and value out of the array $columns?  If so, you want something like this:

```
foreach($columns as $k => $v) {
//in here, $k is the name of the field, and $v is the associated value

}
```